# Currentdate and Nearest date

Tags: date, datetime, batch-file

How do i make a batch file that is echo-ing out the nearest date from a text file?

For example a test file called test2.txt, in text2.text you can see this:

```
11.12.2013 historie (kapittel1, kapittel 2 og kapittel 3).
21.12.2013 matte (kapittelq1, kapittel 2 og kapiwettel 3).
01.12.2013 naturfag (kapittel1q, kapittel 2 og kapiwettel 3).
16.12.2013 example (kapittelq1, kapittel 2 og kapittelwe 3).
12.10.2013 example 2(kapittel1w, kapittel 2 og kapittweel 3).
```

then it would echo out after analyzing the file, and echoing out the nearest date ( from current date) like this:
"

```
The Next test is X days (12.10.2013) and the subject is (example2, and the topics is (kapittel1w, kapittel 2 og kapittweel 3).
this means it is: X hours, X minutes, X secounds *( countdown) *
```

"

How do i do this?

Comment: Do you have powershell?

Comment: No, i dont think so. I only have batch avaliable.

Comment: What OS are you using?  Powershell is in Vista and higher I think. The next date...   Is it always the last line in the file?

Comment: Hello Foxidrive. Im currently running windows 7, but since its a school computer, I do not have access to everything.

Comment: I have powershell, but i prefer it in batch :) ( later on gonna convert to .exe aswell).

Answer (score 0):

with :

```
11.12.2013 historie (kapittel1, kapittel 2 og kapittel 3).
21.12.2013 matte (kapittelq1, kapittel 2 og kapiwettel 3).
01.12.2013 naturfag (kapittel1q, kapittel 2 og kapiwettel 3).
16.12.2013 example (kapittelq1, kapittel 2 og kapittelwe 3).
12.10.2013 example 2(kapittel1w, kapittel 2 og kapittweel 3).
```

result is `20131012`

```
@echo off &setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "file_path=.\test2testtesttest.TXT"

if not exist "!file_path!" echo File "!file_path!" Does Not Exist >&2 & exit /b 2
for /f %%F in ("!file_path!") do  set file_path=%%~sfF


copy nul "%TEMP%\~.ddf" >nul

:: date function provided by carlos
:: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4555&start=15
makecab /D RptFileName="%TEMP%\~.rpt" /D InfFileName="%TEMP%\~.inf" -f "%TEMP%\~.ddf">nul
for /f "tokens=3-7" %%a in ('type "%TEMP%\~.rpt"') do (
   if not defined current-date set "current-date=%%e-%%b-%%c"
   if not defined current-time set "current-time=%%d"
   if not defined weekday set "weekday=%%a"
)
del /q "%TEMP%\~.*"
rem echo %weekday% %current-date% %current-time%
set Jan=01
set Feb=02
set Mar=03
set Apr=04
set May=05
set Jun=06
set Jul=07
set Aug=08
set Sep=09
Set Oct=10
set Nov=11
set Dec=12

for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=-" %%A in ("%current-date%") do (
    set comparable_date=%%A!%%B!%%C
)
rem echo %comparable_date%
set /a nearest_date=99999999
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=. " %%A in (%file_path%) do (

    set /a possible_nearest_date=%%C%%B%%A

    set /a old_result=!nearest_date!-comparable_date
    set /a new_result=!possible_nearest_date!-comparable_date

    if !new_result! LSS !old_result! set /a nearest_date=!possible_nearest_date!
)
if !nearest_date! EQU 99999999 echo something wrong with the file>&2 && endlocal && exit /b 3

set nearest_date=!nearest_date:~-2!.!nearest_date:~4,2!.!nearest_date:~0,4!

echo(
echo(
rem type %file_path%
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=()" %%L in ('type %file_path%^|find "!nearest_date!"') do ( 

    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%t in  ("%%L") do (
        echo The Next Test is on (!nearest_date!^) and subject is ( %%u   with topics   %%M^)
    )   
)
echo(
echo(
endlocal
```

Comment: result: echoing out: "99999999"

Comment: And it cant find the test2.txt , even when i have it in the correct path.

Comment: What file path do you use?Are there quotes?

Comment: atm the file are in the same folder as my "script". ( documents)

Comment: Could you then "convert" it to the main thread that i asked for, ( like the output)

Comment: Count down will be tricky for a simple batch (powershell command will really ease me :- ) ).But the rest is easy.Will update the script.

Comment: The part without countdown is ready.For the rest - it can be done with nasty calculations , embedded jscript or powershell commands - but it will cost me some time to do it...

Comment: will check it. Its totally up to you if you want to do the nasty work :P

Comment: I get the cannot find test2 ( something).txt . weird.

Comment: you need to change `set "file_path=.\test2testtesttest.TXT"` line with your path...

Comment: i saw that now. it works. Now im trying to figure out a cool "output" design for the output to be C:

^^^

Answer (score 0):

Condensed get next event part:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,* DELIMS==" %%c IN ('WMIC OS GET /FORMAT:VALUE') DO IF /I "%%c" == "LocalDateTime" SET CurrentDate=%%d
SET CurrentDate=%CurrentDate:~0,8%

SET NextDate=99999999
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2,3,* DELIMS=. " %%i IN (text2.txt) DO IF %%k%%j%%i GTR %CurrentDate% FOR /F %%r IN ('SET /A NextDate-=%%k%%j%%i') DO IF %%r GTR 0 (
    SET NextDate=%%k%%j%%i
    SET NextSubject=%%l
)

ECHO The Next test is (%NextDate:~6,2%.%NextDate:~4,2%.%NextDate:~0,4%) and the subject is %NextSubject%.
```

Count down timer:

This is a hard part. I already did date logic in batch (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010507/forfiles-command-to-delete-12-hours-old-files-in-bat-file/18014577#18014577)), but it is very time consuming.

Use VBScripting alternative or create a small program to make this hard work.

EDIT: As @npocmaka noticed `WMIC` is not standard in all Windows versions, I'm adding solutions for both parts using VBS.

Batch file:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%d IN ('CSCRIPT /NOLOGO Now.vbs') DO SET CurrentDate=%%d
SET NextDate=99999999
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2,3,* DELIMS=. " %%i IN (text2.txt) DO IF "%%k %%j %%i" GTR "%CurrentDate%" FOR /F %%r IN ('SET /A NextDate-=%%k%%j%%i') DO IF %%r GTR 0 (
    SET NextDate=%%k%%j%%i
    SET "NextSubject=%%l"
)
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2,3,4" %%d IN ('CSCRIPT /NOLOGO DateDiff.vbs %NextDate:~0,4% %NextDate:~4,2% %NextDate:~6,2% 00 00 00 %CurrentDate%') DO ECHO The Next test is %%d days (%NextDate:~6,2%.%NextDate:~4,2%.%NextDate:~0,4%) and the subject is %NextSubject%.
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2,3,4" %%d IN ('CSCRIPT /NOLOGO DateDiff.vbs %NextDate:~0,4% %NextDate:~4,2% %NextDate:~6,2% 00 00 00 %CurrentDate%') DO ECHO this means it is: %%e hours, %%f minutes, %%g seconds
```

Now.vbs:

```
d=Now
WScript.Echo Right("000"&Year(d),4)&" "&Right("0"&Month(d),2)&" "&Right("0"&Day(d),2)&" "&Right("0"&Hour(d),2)&" "&Right("0"&Minute(d),2)&" "&Right("0"&Second(d),2)
```

DateDiff.vbs:

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count <> 12 Then
    WScript.Echo "Syntax: DAYSDIFF yyyy mm dd hh mm ss yyyy mm dd hh mm ss"
Else
    d=DateSerial(WScript.Arguments(0),WScript.Arguments(1),WScript.Arguments(2))+TimeSerial(WScript.Arguments(3),WScript.Arguments(4),WScript.Arguments(5))-DateSerial(WScript.Arguments(6),WScript.Arguments(7),WScript.Arguments(8))-TimeSerial(WScript.Arguments(9),WScript.Arguments(10),WScript.Arguments(11))
    WScript.Echo Cdbl(Fix(d))&" "&Right("0"&Hour(d),2)&" "&Right("0"&Minute(d),2)&" "&Right("0"&Second(d),2)
End IF
```

Comment: For sure is not available on XP home edition. Check this thread.It turns out that makecab is the most universal way to get the date independently from time settings:  http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4555&start=15