# Batch script to check if a file is over a certain age

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm looking for an answer... I've trawled through Google for hours and I'm stuck!

I'm writing a batch script on Windows Server 2008 to be used as an external script by NSClient for a Nagios check.

I've already got the script doing a few different things, I just need it to check a file age aswell! The file is different everyday, I've compensated for that part though. Basically, I'm looking for:

IF %FILE% (insert code to determine over 20 minutes old)
(if it is over 20 minutes old) ECHO BLAH BLAH BLAH
ELSE GOTO :123

Hope you can all help, I'm stuck on this one!!

Thanks

Will

Comment: I'm going to change that a little... I'm not looking for file age, I'm looking for modified time...

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18010507) can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will return `%age%` variable set to `1` if `older than 20 minutes`, otherwise set to `0`.

Launch it like this: `Checkage.bat "c:\folder\filename.txt"`

```
@echo off
:: Wmic removes regional differences
:: XP Pro can have some filename errors due to the short filename bug
:: XP Home does not have WMIC.EXE

set NumMin=20

call :CheckMins "%~f1"
echo %age%
goto :EOF

:CheckMins
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "stamp=%YYYY% %MM% %DD% %HH% %Min%"
call :DateToMinutes %stamp% NowMins
set "file=%~sf1"

:: can use CreationDate instead of lastmodified

WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name="%file:\=\\%" get lastmodified | find "." >file.tmp
for /f %%a in (file.tmp) do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "filestamp=%YYYY% %MM% %DD% %HH% %Min%"
del file.tmp 2>nul
if not defined yyyy goto :EOF

call :DateToMinutes %filestamp% FileMins

set /a MinsOld=%NowMins%-%FileMins%
if %MinsOld% gtr %NumMin% (set age=1) else (set age=0)
goto :EOF

:DateToMinutes
setlocal
set yy=%1&set mm=%2&set dd=%3&set hh=%4&set nn=%5
if 1%yy% LSS 200 if 1%yy% LSS 170 (set yy=20%yy%) else (set yy=19%yy%)
set /a dd=100%dd%%%100,mm=100%mm%%%100
set /a z=14-mm,z/=12,y=yy+4800-z,m=mm+12*z-3,j=153*m+2
set /a j=j/5+dd+y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-2472633
if 1%hh% LSS 20 set hh=0%hh%
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} EQU {p} if "%hh%" NEQ "12" set hh=1%hh%&set/a hh-=88
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} EQU {a} if "%hh%" EQU "12" set hh=00
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} GEQ {a} set nn=%nn:~0,2%
set /a hh=100%hh%%%100,nn=100%nn%%%100,j=j*1440+hh*60+nn
endlocal&set %6=%j%&goto :EOF
```