# deleting files older than 30 days with a .bat fle

Tags: batch-file

I am tring to write a .bat file to delete files older then 30 days in a specific folder I have tried several diifrent format with no luck.

the closest one  i got is

del C:\temp\temp d -30

edit.....
ok so i got forfilles /p c:\temp\temp /d 
how can I make it use the date when its ran instead of always having to go in and change it evrytime I run it and get them to delete them now
can any one help me out
thanks

Comment: Check this one out for some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010507/forfiles-command-to-delete-12-hours-old-files-in-bat-file

Answer (score 1):

There is no such switch available to the **DEL**ete command. Type `FORFILES /?` into a console window, read the output taking special note of the **/D** parameter.